# File copied in dockerfile: Not found if in specific location

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have this dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

COPY .docker/certificates/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
COPY .docker/certificates/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
COPY .docker/config/options-ssl-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/options-ssl-nginx.conf
COPY .docker/config/ssl-dhparams.pem /etc/nginx/ssl-dhparams.pem
COPY .docker/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN chmod +r /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
```

I have this in my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;

    # Why can't this file be found?
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    # ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem;
    # ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    ...
}
```

Nginx crashes with:

`[emerg] 7#7: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)`

However, if I change the location of `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem` to, for example, `/etc/nginx/fullchaim.pem` and `/etc/nginx/privkey.pem` and update the nginx configuration, it *does* find the files and works as expected.

Here's the service definition in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  nginx-server:
    container_name: "nginx-server"
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: .docker/dockerfiles/NginxDockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - static-content:/home/docker/code/static
      - letsencrypt-data:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-data:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
      - api
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
    networks:
      - api-network
      - main

# Commented out to verify that the files aren't being deleted by certbot
#  certbot:
#    image: certbot/certbot
#    container_name: "certbot"
#    depends_on:
#      - nginx-server
#    restart: unless-stopped
#    volumes:
#      - letsencrypt-data:/etc/letsencrypt
#      - certbot-data:/var/www/certbot
#    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'sleep 30s && trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
```

The intention is to use `fullchain.pem` as an initial certificate until one can be requested from let's encrypt. Note that, at this point, there is no `certbot` service, and the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com` directory is not referenced anywhere else at all (only in `NginxDockerfile` and `nginx.conf`), so it *shouldn't* be an issue of another service deleting the files. Rebuilding with `--no-cache` does not help.

Why can't nginx find the files in this specific location, but can find them if copied to a different location?

**EDIT:** As suggested, I ended up using a host volume instead. This didn't work when the host volume was located inside the repository (`root_of_context/path/to/gitignored/directory/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt`, but did work with `/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt`, which I personally find ugly, but oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volumes are mounted on run, so after your container is built.
Since you mounted `letsencrypt-data` on `/etc/letsencrypt`, Nginx is going to look for your files into `letsencrypt-data`.
I don't know the purpose of this mount but I guess your container would succeed in running if you removed `- letsencrypt-data:/etc/letsencrypt` from `volumes`.

Comment: I just found this out by also updating `docker-compose.yml` to say `- letsencrypt-data:/etc/nginx`, which causes it to fail just the same. How would I make this a named volume (so it can be shared with `certbot`) and still copy files into it? Do I need to copy them to a different location in `NginxDockerfile` and then run a script to copy them to `letsencrypt-data`?

Comment: If you need to share files between containers, I would suggest to put your files inside a folder OUTSIDE of your containers; mount this folder as a volume on both containers and access those files inside inside containers. You can look at https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose